# Number of ways $f(n,k)$ which we can split on $k$ equal rewards among $n$ students.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Please for your help.

On the lecture we determined number of ways $f(n,k)$ which we can split on $k$ equal rewards among $n$ students.

We made two separable class:

$A_1$ = here $n$-th person doesn't get a reward

$A_2$ = everything else

And we had these

$(A_1)= f(n-1,k)$  this is ok

$(A_2)= f(n,k-1)$  I don't know why there is $k-1$

Then we had $f(n,k)= f(n-1,k) + f(n, k-1)$

Can somebody explain to me why there is k-1 in $(A_2)$

Comment: Think about the class $A_2$. In class $A_2$, the $n$:th person **does** get a reward. That sort of happens before all the other rewards are distributed, and therefore there are $k-1$ rewards instead of $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the other cases, the $n^{th}$ person will receive at least 1 reward, so the number of rewards to take care of gets reduced by 1, as we can be sure that one reward goes to Mr. $n$ !